# How to generate date ranges in SQL, given any To_date to to_date from given table?

Tags: sql, oracle, date, oracle10g

I have written below query to generate a date sequence where Date ranges span 12 months and The first date range starts at the from_date column and ends with to_date.
for example for ITP_no 1 from_date is 1-Apr-07  and to_date is 31-Mar-09 then op shoud be 
ITP_NO
1      APR 2007- MAR 2008 
1      APR 2008- MAR 2009

```
Below is input table

ITP_NO  BILL_AMOUNT FROM_DATE   TO_DATE
1   58      1-Apr-07            31-Mar-08
1   58      1-Apr-07            31-Mar-08
1   58      1-Apr-07            31-Mar-08
1   58      1-Apr-07            31-Mar-08
1   58      1-Apr-07            31-Mar-08
1   116     1-Jan-09            31-Dec-11
```

query:

```
    SELECT  ITP_NO ,level,
            BILL_AMOUNT ,From_Date,TO_DATE,
TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(From_Date, (LEVEL - 1) * 12), 'MON-YYYY' ) || ' - '|| 
TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(From_Date,  LEVEL * 12)-1, 'Mon-YYYY') as End_Date 
FROM (
            SELECT  ITP_NO,
                        BILL_AMOUNT,
                        From_Date,
                        TO_DATE 
            FROM test123

      )
CONNECT BY  ADD_MONTHS(From_Date, (LEVEL - 1) * 12)<TO_DATE
```

output given by :

```
ITP_NO LEVEL BILL_AMOUNT    FROM_DATE   TO_DATE     END_DATE



1   1   58      1-Apr-07    31-Mar-08   Apr-07-Mar-08
1   1   58      1-Apr-07    31-Mar-08   Apr-07-Mar-08
1   1   58      1-Apr-07    31-Mar-08   Apr-07-Mar-08
1   1   58      1-Apr-07    31-Mar-08   Apr-07-Mar-08
1   1   58      1-Apr-07    31-Mar-08   Apr-07-Mar-08
1   2   116     1-Jan-09    31-Dec-11   Jan-10-Dec-10
1   3   116     1-Jan-09    31-Dec-11   Jan-11-Dec-11
1   3   116     1-Jan-09    31-Dec-11   Jan-11-Dec-11
1   3   116     1-Jan-09    31-Dec-11   Jan-11-Dec-11
1   2   116     1-Jan-09    31-Dec-11   Jan-10-Dec-10
1   3   116     1-Jan-09    31-Dec-11   Jan-11-Dec-11
1   3   116     1-Jan-09    31-Dec-11   Jan-11-Dec-11
1   3   116     1-Jan-09    31-Dec-11   Jan-11-Dec-11
1   2   116     1-Jan-09    31-Dec-11   Jan-10-Dec-10
1   3   116     1-Jan-09    31-Dec-11   Jan-11-Dec-11
1   3   116     1-Jan-09    31-Dec-11   Jan-11-Dec-11
1   3   116     1-Jan-09    31-Dec-11   Jan-11-Dec-11
1   2   116     1-Jan-09    31-Dec-11   Jan-10-Dec-10
```

> expected O/P

```
  ITP_NO    BILL_AMOUNT FROM_DATE   TO_DATE END_DATE        
1   58  1-Apr-07    31-Mar-08   Apr-07- Mar-08  
1   58  1-Apr-07    31-Mar-08   Apr-07- Mar-08  
1   58  1-Apr-07    31-Mar-08   Apr-07- Mar-08  
1   58  1-Apr-07    31-Mar-08   Apr-07- Mar-08  
1   58  1-Apr-07    31-Mar-08   Apr-07- Mar-08  
1   116 1-Jan-09    31-Dec-11   Jan-09- Dec-10  
1   116 1-Jan-09    31-Dec-11   Jan-11- Dec-11
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: @jarlh M using Oracle 10G

Comment: Why do you want so many records for ITP_NO 58..the record is just duplicates. Try grouping by and the order by end_date

Comment: @XING basically I want generate date ranges from from_date to to_date in the span of 12 months and the table contain some duplicate records so want to show all of them. If you look at bill amount 116's out put it's divide into two part i.e. 31-Dec-11 Jan-09- Dec-10 and 31-Dec-11 Jan-11- Dec-11. for e.g if the difference between from_date and to_date is 4 year then the end_date should be split into 4 separate year from from_date to End_date

Answer (score 0):

I think that something like here may be useful. Add `row_number()` in inner query and use it in `connect by` clause:

```
select t.*, 
       to_char(add_months(From_Date, (level - 1) * 12), 'yyyy-mm') || ' - '||  
       to_char(add_months(From_Date, (level * 12)) - 1, 'yyyy-mm') period
  from (
    select t.*, row_number() over (order by from_date, to_date) rn
      from test123 t) t
  connect by add_months(From_Date, (level - 1) * 12) <= to_date 
             and prior rn = rn and prior dbms_random.value is not null
```

There is difference in Your output and mine for 116, but this is 3 years period.

The part `prior rn = rn and prior dbms_random.value is not null` is the trick used in hierarchical queries to prevent `ORA-01436: CONNECT BY loop in user data`.

<sup>[Oracle Row Generator Techniques](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Oracle_Row_Generator_Techniques)</sup>

Test:

```
create table test123 (itp_no number(3), bill_amount number(6), from_date date, to_date date);
insert into test123 values (1,  58, date '2007-04-01', date '2008-03-31');
insert into test123 values (1,  58, date '2007-04-01', date '2008-03-31');
insert into test123 values (1,  58, date '2007-04-01', date '2008-03-31');
insert into test123 values (1,  58, date '2007-04-01', date '2008-03-31');
insert into test123 values (1,  58, date '2007-04-01', date '2008-03-31');
insert into test123 values (1, 116, date '2009-01-01', date '2011-12-31');


ITP_NO BILL_AMOUNT FROM_DATE   TO_DATE             RN PERIOD
------ ----------- ----------- ----------- ---------- -----------------
     1          58 2007-04-01  2008-03-31           1 2007-04 - 2008-03
     1          58 2007-04-01  2008-03-31           2 2007-04 - 2008-03
     1          58 2007-04-01  2008-03-31           3 2007-04 - 2008-03
     1          58 2007-04-01  2008-03-31           4 2007-04 - 2008-03
     1          58 2007-04-01  2008-03-31           5 2007-04 - 2008-03
     1         116 2009-01-01  2011-12-31           6 2009-01 - 2009-12
     1         116 2009-01-01  2011-12-31           6 2010-01 - 2010-12
     1         116 2009-01-01  2011-12-31           6 2011-01 - 2011-12
```